# Row's content independent clickable areas

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

**NOTE: if you are here because you face similar issue, please ensure you read and try all answers provided. It appeared that under some circumstances one may work better than another. So do your own tests as well!**

**PREFACE**

I got listview's row layout like this (this is stripped down version of my real layout so do not comment of things like single elements wrapped in LinearLayout etc. - it just to illustrate the issue - final version got more elements there):

[image]

XML file is below for reference, but I shortly describe what I want to achieve:

- blue box (icon) and "usually long text here" TextView are row "real" content (`item_main_container`). It can be anything - it shall be irrelevant. This layer content is not clickable. In fact (but I just realized that) I should show the "blue box" to be half covered by red and half covered by green box from next layer.
- the red and green boxes are views I bind row's OnCliclListeners to (wrapped in `item_click_area_container`)- I just want user to be able to tap on the row, no matter what's `item_main_container`'s content really is (so these red/green are transparent in the app). **NOTE:** These are set transparent on the image so you can see `item_main_content` thru it, but it is just for demonstration purposes. Please also note red and green represent **separate** actions and I need to be able to have more elements on `item_click_area_container` layer to be able to handle more actions depending on where user tapped.
- the yellow area (`button_bar_container`) holds buttons user may want to tap.

So basically `item_click_area_container` overlays `item_main_container`, but not `button_bar_container`, which is above `item_click_area_container` otherwise user would not be able to tap on any of its button. In perspective it would be:

[image]

Layout outline looks like this:

[image]

---

**PROBLEM**

I am unable to make `item_click_area_container` stretch correctly to overlay **whole** `item_main_container` as it should, despite my efforts. Since `"usually long text here"` text can be of any length, I do not know what's the height of `item_main_container`. In the XML below there's `android:layout_height="100dp` - this works in terms I see all row elements, however for longer texts `item_click_area_container` height is too small. But if I replace it with `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` then the whole `item_click_area_container` is not visible, which defeats the purpose.

---

**QUESTIONS**

1. Why this is not working as expected and/or how to fix that?
2. Is there any better way of having content independent click areas than using approach like mine `item_click_area_container` (but no OnTouchListener based solutions)?

---

**LAYOUT XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/item_main_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView 
               android:id="@+id/item_avatar" 
               android:layout_width="40dp" 
               android:layout_height="40dp" 
               android:background="#0000ff" 
               android:src="@drawable/icon_help"/>

            <LinearLayout 
               android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:orientation="vertical">

               <TextView android:id="@+id/item_body" 
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                 android:text="Usually long text here..." 
                 android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
               android:id="@+id/item_click_area_container" 
               android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
               android:layout_height="100dp">
            <LinearLayout 
               android:id="@+id/green_click" 
               android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
               android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
               android:layout_weight="1" 
               android:background="#7700ff00">
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout 
               android:id="@+id/red_click" 
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_weight="2" 
               android:background="#77ff0000">
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
       android:id="@+id/button_bar_container" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="50dp" 
       android:layout_marginTop="3dp" 
       android:background="#ffff00">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**EDIT #1**

I think I could use `OnTouchListener`, and in `onTouch()` check `event.getAction()` and if it is `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` read X/Y of the event and check against view's bounds. This might do the trick, still, I would prefer to stick to OnClickListener alone if possible. Not to mention it'd help to understand what the current culprit is, especially layout renders correctly in ADT

Comment: I believe adding an `OnClickListener` to `item_main_container` will also work.

Comment: I first rejected this hint, but after a break I lurked in the docs again and I think it indeed could be the way. You can use onTouchListener, check `event.getAction()` and if it is `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` read X/Y of the event. This shall suffice, however I'd need to keep the tap areas in the code, which is not the most perfect. Still, it can be a progress. Need to investigate. Thanks :)

Comment: Right, should be "button_bar_container" as seen on overlay. Corrected. And yes, I also think it shall just work - but it does not and I do not know why.

Comment: I have reproduced this and it works as expected: all views are clickable. What is your problem exactly? You want `item_click_area_container` to be the exact height of `item_main_container`? That's it? please do explain better

Comment: @SherifelKhatib clickablity is not a problem. Layout is - please see "PROBLEM" section in my quesion. If it is not clear - let me know I'll try to work on that part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go this layout will work. The simple solution is to align the 4 sides of `item_click_area_container` to the corresponding 4 sides of `item_main_container` using these 4 lines:

```
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/item_main_container"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_main_container"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/item_main_container"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/item_main_container"
```

Here is your Layout with wrap_content height. No more hardcoded sizes (:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/item_main_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/item_avatar"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#0000ff"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_body"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Usually long text hasdkfn ash jsjkgh sjhgjk hasjkh ash fjk hasdjkh fkjash jkdf hjkasdh fjkhasjkg hjkasjkd hfjkash gsdgh kgh sdfh fjksah djkfasd jkg jsdf asgjf sg sd agfgas fjhasg f asdgf gjhsdg sdjhsdg fasdfjhs agjhfg  adf asdg jh dvhsdvjhas gdh fv gsfjivhdfvjksfgjkdhjhixcgzvjk gdshg dfg v gvgdfgvjkshvjksdgvsdvere..."
                    android:textColor="#000" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/item_main_container"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_main_container"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/item_main_container"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/item_main_container"
            android:id="@+id/item_click_area_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/green_click"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#7700ff00" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/red_click"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="#77ff0000" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_bar_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="#ffff00" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nice trick to solve the issue, yet after all the tests I consider Marina's approach clearer due to lack of "anchor dependencies". Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just a note, hope this will help someone someday :) - I managed to create another layout which causes similar troubles to described in my question and which I was not able to address using FrameLayout approach **on Android 2.x** (it worked in higher versions), but,  fortunately Sherif's trick worked fine. So I am now a bit sad I wasn't able to split the bounty in half...

Comment: Hehe @WebnetMobile.com no problem. Think of it positively: We have two solutions now.

Comment: Your solutions works in more cases that Marina's. Still, 50%-50% would be better, but since I can't go that way, I changed my mind :) Cannot reassign bounty though.

Comment: lol no problem though I cant really remember this question. Anyway I just want to say that I really like the comment you added on the top of your question for future ppl looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could try replacing your

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">...</RelativeLayout>
```

with a

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">...</FrameLayout>
```

Then set the params of `item_click_area_container` to `fill_parent`/`match_parent` to make it grow to cover the same area than `item_main_container`.

If you use classes that extend `LinearLayout` that handle the actions you need for the red and green regions, you should be ok.

Comment: I've tried this, but it not really works as I hoped. I noticed the same odd behaviour as with RelativeLayout lack of correct stretching. Will try some other combinations with FrameLayout anyway, so thanks for a hint. but I am not sure it will work for all cases due to limited alignment options comparing to RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

On individual element in your layout.xml android:onClick

```
    <LinearLayout 
       android:id="@+id/red_click" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_weight="2" 
       android:background="#77ff0000">
   android:onClick="redAreaClicked"
    </LinearLayout>
```

in your java file write a method redAreaClicked() with following code.

```
    public void redAreaClicked(View v) {
      RelativeLayout ParentRow = (RelativeLayout) v.getParent();
      final int position = mList.getPositionForView(ParentRow);
      // more code here..
    }
```

This should give you position in the list. i.e row number.
But for this to work You will have to move all your child views (Coloured Views, inyour case linear layout) inside a single parent. Using relative layout I think that would be very much feasible.

Or else you can use view.getId() and compare, in order to get parent view. And then determine its position in list.

You can do same for other colored areas.

Comment: This is not a solution. The only area click listeners could be attached to is content of `item_click_area_container`.